# Real roots of $x^6+15x^2-60x+1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I prove that $f(x)= x^6+15x^2-60x+1=0$ can't have three real roots.

First I derive two times for see the signs of derivatives and got that  $ 6x^5+30x-60=0$ and $ 30x^4+30=0$ which is always positive but hoe can I conclude that $f$ can't have three roots.

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: "Always positive " second derivative means the slope is always increasing.  If the polynomial crosses the $y=0$ line three times, what has to happen?

Comment: Also, since it's a polynomial of even degree with real coefficients, it can't have an odd number of real roots.

Comment: Ok, ok I understand, really thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second derivate is always positive. Hence, the first derivate can have at most one root. Hence, the function can have at most two roots.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Since all coefficients are real, complex roots of the polynomial should go by pairs $x$ and $\bar{x}$.

Comment: Wow, a very easy way to prove the claim, chapeau!

Comment: What if two of roots are real and four imaginary?

Comment: @RayeesAhmad, according to the problem we only need to show that the polynomial can't have three real roots.

Answer (score 3):

Use rule of change signs
The number of positive real roots of $f(x)$ can't exceed the number of change of signs in $f(x)$ 
and
The number of negative real roots of $f(x)$ can't exceed the number of change of signs in $f(-x)$

Now you see $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ has one and zero sign changes.Hence there can be only one real root but then f(x) will have odd number of imaginary roots which is not possible.Hence $f(x)$ has no real root.